# Predicate with 2 lists and variables in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate that looks like this:

`predicate(List1,List2,Variable1,Variable2)`

I want is to be true whenever List1 contains Variable1 on the same position as List2 contains Variable2. Example: `?- predicate([1,2,2,3,4,5], [a,a,b,c,d,e], 4, d)
         true.`

And please don't get me wrong, I don't want the full code to the problem. I am simply looking for someone to maybe push me in the right direction, the thought about how to go about this problem.

EDIT:
As to the answer below I tried to create a rule considering the first statement. But it doesn't work and I get a ton of errors.

```
predicate([],[],Variable1,Variable2)

predicate([A|_],[B|_],Variable1,Variable2):-
    A is Variable1,
    B is Variable2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicate holds if

- `List1` starts with `Variable1` and `List2` starts with `Variable2`

or if

- `List1` starts with whatever and `List2` starts with whatever and the predicate holds for the tail of `List1` and the tail of `List2`

---

Regarding your edit:

Your first definition (which by the way lacks a `.`) says that the predicate holds for empty lists. This is not the case, since the lists does *not* contain `Variable1` and `Variable2` at the same positions. Try something like `[Variable1|_]` for instance.

As for the second one, you're onto something. I would however suggest you express it like `[Variable1|_], ..., Variable1`, i.e. let prologs matching do the job of making sure the head of the list equals the variable.

Comment: Do you mean that those are 2 rules that I should create to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I mean. I tried it out and it seems to work fine :-) If you need further guidance, update your question and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Should the predicate hold given two empty lists?

Comment: No, that was my bad. The predicate should be like this: predicate(List1,List2,E1,E2).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61774/discussion-between-fjodor-and-aioobe).

Comment: Did you solve it? If so, feel free to accept the answer.